# Copiar QVector local para QVector de Classe

Tags: c++, qt

É o seguinte estou fazendo na unha um gráfico LineChart para um trabalho de aula, estou com enormes dificuldades com a linguagem C++, em certa parte do código passo por parametro um `QVector<QPoint>`, e quero pintar na função `DrawLine` esses points, mas para isso pensei que copiar o `QVector<QPoint>` que mando para o método, para um `QVector<QPoint>` global da classe mas não consigo copiar, alguém me da uma ajuda ?

```
#pragma once
#include <QFrame>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QPaintEvent>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QVector>

class LineChart : public QFrame
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        LineChart();
        void addSeries(QVector<QPoint> series, QColor color);
        void setAxisX(QVector<QString> values);
        void setAxisY(QVector<QString> values);
        void setLabelX(QString name);
        void setLabelY(QString name);
        void setTitle(QString title);
        void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* paint);

        // keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event);
    private:
        //QFrame *frame;
        QGridLayout *layout;
        QLabel *label;
        int x0,x1,y0,y1;
        QPoint *point;
        QPoint *point2;
        QVector<QPoint> *vector;
        //QPushButton *button;
};

void LineChart::addSeries(QVector<QPoint> series, QColor color){
    vector = new QVector<QPoint>;
    vector = series;
}

void LineChart::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event){
    QFrame::paintEvent(event);
    QPainter painter(this);

    qDebug() << point->rx() ;
    qDebug() << point->ry();
    qDebug() << point2->rx() ;
    qDebug() << point2->ry();

    //painter.drawLine(point->rx(),point2->ry(),point->rx(),point2->ry());
    for(int i = 0 ; i< vector->length() ; i++){

    }

    qDebug() << "paintEventinvocado!";
}
```

Comment: Você pode meramente atribuir um QVector ao outro, pelo `operator=`. Tentou isso?

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente, este código de exemplo mostra alguns problemas em conceitos básicos da linguagem C++ (Você aparenta ter um conhecimento da linguagem Java e esta utilizando C++ como se fosse ela). Seria interessante você estudar esse conceitos fazendo programas mais básicos antes de criar uma aplicação complexa com interface gráfica.

Alguns desses problemas são:

- Uso excessivo de ponteiros para casos onde não são necessários. (`QVector<QPoint> * vector` declarado como variável membro de `LineChart`, por exemplo)
- Não definição de construtor de cópia, operador de atribuição e destrutor quando sua classe possui ponteiros. Não ter isso faz com que memória seja vazada em alguns momentos ( C++ não faz coleta de lixo, você tem que chamar `delete` quando terminar de usar espaços de memória alocados dinamicamente com o `new`) e que objetos internos da classe sejam compartilhados entre cópias desta.

Tendo dito isso, o problema no seu código que faz com que você não consiga copiar o vetor esta no seguinte trecho:

```
vector = new QVector<QPoint>;
vector = series;
```

Aqui `vector` é um `QVector<QPoint> *` e logo na linha seguinte você tenta atribuir uma variável do tipo `QVector<QPoint>` ao ponteiro, o que não é valido. Para efetuar a cópia é necessário derreferenciar o ponteiro como no código à seguir:

```
*vector = series; // *vector é um QVector<QPoint>
```

Uma solução ainda mais idiomática utilizando os recurso do C++ é usar o construtor de cópia da classe `QVector`, sendo assim o código inteiro da função se tornaria:

```
vector = new QVector<QPoint>(series);
```

Criando um novo objeto que já é uma cópia do original.

Comment: Nota: `QVector` implementa **copy-on-write**. Então criar cópias desse objeto é leve e não acarreta cópias de todos os elementos.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal Editei minha resposta para retirar a ressalva sobre o custo da cópia. Obrigado pela informação! :)